# Как точно определить микросекунды в Duration()?

Tags: flutter, dart

Как точно делать паузы в микросекундах в:

```
sleep(Duration(microseconds: <?>))
```

или в:

```
Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: <?>))
```

, если выходные данные будут равны, например, `7.166666666666667` или `8.333333333333334` или `9.5` или еще что-то подобное?

Comment: Паузы в 9.5 **микро**секунд? Для чего вам это? Похоже на забивание шурупов микроскопом.

Answer (score 1):

Дисклеймер - вы не сможете гарантировать такой точности. Любой `sleep()` гарантирует только то, что он сработает **не раньше** заданной задержки. Девайс призадумался, система подвисла - сработает позже.

Как с этим поступить?

Заведите переменную в которой будет время с прошлого апдейта и проверяйте точную дельту. Она будет больше. Что с этим делать дальше - вопрос большой и зависит от вашей задачи и требований.